# What is the opposite of 'a false dawn'

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions

What is the opposite of a false dawn, a false dawn being "a promising situation which comes to nothing". 
The sentence I'm thinking of would be something like:
They started off well and it was not a false dawn it was ...?

Comment: False is not true. Dawn is not dusk. So you must mean a true dusk, right?

Comment: @tchrist Very logical thinking there, you could be a programmer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resplendent sunrise of good fortune**

> The day began full of promise, and it was no false dawn, but rather a resplendent sunrise of good fortune.  They met his price, and his commission check was as good as in his pocket . . .

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "bona ﬁde daybreak" might work for you.

Google finds a hint that this has all been done before: "Apple, along with Windows 7, is busily ensuring that this false dawnbecomes (sic) a bona ﬁde daybreak".

Answer (score -1):

*[dark horse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dark-horse)*

> A candidate or competitor about whom little is known but who unexpectedly wins or succeeds

*[surprise](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/surprise?q=surprise)!*
**1** An unexpected or astonishing event, fact, or thing: *the announcement was a complete surprise*